# How to add a custom link to login form block with hook_form_alter

Tags: forms, users, navigation

How to add a link with custom path to my login block with hook_form_alter. I 've created a custom module but i dont know what to add to my hook_form_alter function.

Comment: Have you read [`hook_form_alter()` API docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and [Form API reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7)? If so, look at [#markup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup). If not, then read it now, then look at #markup, then try and show us what have you tried :) We cannot write manuals here, and we cannot work as free code writing service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Drupal 7 you can use **[#markup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup-attribute) attribute**, as suggested by MOLOT

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter()
 */
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_login':
    case 'user_login_block':
      $form['link'] = array('#markup' => l(t('Link text'),'node'));
      break;
  }
}
```

Note:

- **[hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)**
- **[Forms API reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup-attribute)**

Comment: I was just reading the form api, I used 
if($form_id == 'user_login_block'){
  //
}
But this din't work. Thank you anyway :D